# HttpHelpers routing methods in mounted rails engine results in uninitialized constant "controller name"

Tags: rails-engines, uninitialized-constant

My environment:

- Rails 3.2.8
- Ruby 1.9.3p194
- Fedora 16 x86_64

This problem seems specific to Rails Engines.

It seems that when using the `HttpHelpers` in a Rails Engine's routes file, I get "uninitialized constant Controller" when accessing a route via a browser. But, if I use a URL matcher in the Engine's routes file, it routes correctly.

Here's how I created a failing example:

```
$ rails plugin new my_engine --mountable
$ cd my_engine
$ rails g controller things index
$ rails s -p 3005
```

The controller generator uses the `HttpHelpers#get` method by default, so at this point the Rails Engine's `config/routes.rb` file looks like:

```
MyEngine::Engine.routes.draw do
  get "things/index"

end
```

And, the `test/dummy` application's `config/routes.rb` file looks like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  mount MyEngine::Engine => "/my_engine"
end
```

So, I should be able to hit `http://locahost:3005/my_engine/things/index` and see the **Things#index** view from the Engine.  But, instead in the browser I see:

> Routing Error
>
> uninitialized constant ThingsController

If I manually change the Engine's `config/routes.rb` file to:

```
MyEngine::Engine.routes.draw do
  #get "things/index"
  match "things/index" => "things#index"

end
```

... and hit `http://locahost:3005/my_engine/things/index`, I see the correct **Things#index** view.

I noticed that when I use the `HttpHelpers#get` method in the Engine's `config/routes.rb` file, and run `rake routes` from the `test/dummy` directory, I see:

```
$ rake routes
my_engine  /my_engine MyEngine::Engine

Routes for MyEngine::Engine:
things_index GET /things/index(.:format) things#index
```

But, if I change the Engine's `config/routes.rb` file to use the URL matcher method, I see:

```
$ rake routes
my_engine  /my_engine MyEngine::Engine

Routes for MyEngine::Engine:
things_index  /things/index(.:format) my_engine/things#index
```

Notice that when using the URL matcher, the controller and action are correctly namespaced under the engine.  While, when using the `HttpHelpers#get`, the controller and action seem to be non-namespaced.

So, my question: Am I doing something wrong here?  Or, is this a bug?

Note:  I searched the rails issues and didn't see anything directly related to this.  Though I did see several other engine and routing issues.